# preg_replace "%2520" with a space

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have a blog page on my website where a user edit's a post by going to a URL like this... `http://www.example.com/blog?edit=blog post here`. The script used to replace the spaces with `%20` like it should but now it is replacing the spaces with `%2520` and now the script can't search the database because there is no post called `blog20post20here`. I was going to go down the path of preg_replace, so I tried this...

```
preg_replace("/%2520/"," ",$_GET['edit']);
```

but that didn't seem to work.

I have never used `preg_replace()` and I just now read up on it in the manual. If someone could either point me down the right path and or show me how to correctly use `preg_replace` that would be awesome.

Comment: you're using the wrong tool, just use urldecode

Comment: you may be better finding the reason the url's changed and fixing the issue there.

Comment: You might want to look on urldecode() instead, right from the start (before any stray replacement leaves you with strange sequences)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you're double-escaping somewhere when generating the urls. %25 is the coding for the % character, so it sounds like it's going from %20 to %2520.

As an aside, there's better ways to decode that url (urldecode() for example), so perhaps preg_replace isn't really necessary...

EDIT: oh, and you should just use urlencode to generate the url in the first place.

Answer (score -1):

**For %2520**

```
<?php echo urldecode(urldecode($_GET['edit'])); ?>
```

**For %20**

```
<?php echo urldecode($_GET['edit']); ?>
```